# Удалить сайдбар с помощью метаполя в Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Добрый день. Хочу на сайте WP сделать отключение сайдбара в записи с помощью мета поля. Допустим, я создал мета-бокс, в котором есть выпадающее меню с выбором значений. Одно из значений - "без сайдбара" - вывожу с помощью

```
get_post_meta($post->ID, 'meta_nosidebar', true) ;
```

То есть при его выборе, сайдбар должен полностью удалиться со страницы. Но вопрос в том, что я недогоняю как его применить в коде шаблона. К примеру в нем такая конструкция в single.php для вывода сайдбара

```
<div id="secondary" class="widget-area;>
    <?php if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Post Sidebar')): endif; ?>
</div>
```

Я пока только добавлял значения метаполей в классы к элементам, после чего правил стили, но display:none для сайдбара - не вариант, а в PHP пока не очень силен. Помогите, плиз!

Comment: <?php if (meta_field_val == cheked){ ?>  <div id="secondary" class="widget-area;>
    <?php if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Post Sidebar')): endif; ?>
</div> <?php } ?>

Comment: У меня в этом поле будут еще значения, вроде левого сайдбара и тому подобное

Comment: if (meta_field_val[1] == cheked) {}

Comment: if (meta_field_val[2] == 'left') { //this is code }

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую установить Toolset Types если не сильны в PHP. Там, с его помошью можно настроить без знаний програмирования дополнительные поля для разных типов постов, таксономий и установить им параметр `Conditional Display`, который дает возможность установить показ того или иного елемента в зависимости от состояния других елементов или кондиций полей.

К слову, также можно заполнять поля динамически в  Toolset Types, тоесть, в вашем случае просто выводить в `select` список возможных опций сайдбаров(например которые вы регистрируете с помощью функкции в теме, пример вывода всех доступных сайдбаров в поле выбора написан ниже), а ниже устанавливать отображение поля в зависимости от выбраного прежнее параметра пользывателем.

Пример вывода всех доступных сайдбаров в теме для поля выбора:

1. Создаем новое поля для нужного типа записи с именем например "Доступные сайдбари" с помощью Toolset Types, устанавливаем только одно имя по умолчанию "Без сайдбара" и значение нему например `none`
2. В functions.php добавляем код для разширения списка нашего поля.
3. Устанавливаем логичское отображение настроек с помощью Toolset Types
   в зависимости от выбора.

Код для пункта 2:

```
 add_filter( "wpt_field_options", "s_attach_select", 10, 3);
    function s_attach_select( $options, $title, $type ){
    switch( $title ){
        case "Доступные сайдбары:":
            $options = array();

            foreach ($GLOBALS["wp_registered_sidebars"] as $sidebar) {
                $options[] = array(
                    "#value" => $sidebar->id,
                    "#title" => $sidebar->name,
                );
            }
            break;
    }
    return $options;
}
```